# HTTP GET request with Android is not working

Tags: android, httpwebrequest

I am trying to access a RESTfull webserver. The link is [Railyatri](http://railyatri.in/l/ajax/location.json?t=16518&s=2013-03-05). When I am access this through my android app, I am getting empty response. When I do that same thing through my PC's browser I get the required data (JSON).

This is how I am making the http request in android

```
    HttpClient stageClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try
    {
    HttpResponse response = stageClient.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if(statusCode == 200)
    {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            data.append(line);
            isSuccess = true;
        }               
    }
    else
    {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException clientProtocolException) {
    }
    catch (IOException ioException) {  
    }
```

I get the Status Code as 200. 
Can somebody point out what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Its giving the empty in browser also... Check it..

Comment: I am getting empty response in mobile's browser...

Comment: Its is not possible. It giving empty on computer and working fine in mobile..

Comment: @TGMCians: its the other way round. You can checkout the link in the question.

Comment: You might want  to try httpGet.setHeader("Accept","application/json"); tell the server what kind of data your andoird app is looking forward to accept

Comment: @Manoj : I also get empty response from my PC browser like TGMCians.

Comment: Its a problem with setting the cookie for that particular site. Now I am setting the cookie before making request and it works fine on my mobile (Android 4.1.2). Thanks guys... :)